# Is Archimedes’ proof correct?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I began studying Archimedes’ work "on the sphere and cylinder".
I currently believe that proof for proposition 3 is not good. I attached the pages for reference.
Now, I don't understand why he believes there's some king of a relationship between the angles and the ratios he states (bottom of p.6). It seems to me that he bases his demonstration solely on the angles' size when he does the correlation between the elements of the circle and the initial magnitudes. In other words, I don't see any relationship between the circle and his previous construct (the right triangle) to justify the ratio relationships (i.e. MK/LK > OC/OH). The only link between the two seems to be the size of their angles, but I don't see how this justifies the relationships he mentions further.

What do I get wrong?

[image][image]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, you are asking why the angle inequality $\angle HOC \, < \, \angle LKM$ implies the ratio inequality $MK : LK > OC : OH$. Correct?

Comment: yes, basically yes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this work was not destined to schoolboys, but to scholars. Hence some obvious passages might be omitted. I'd suggest you to read the completely different "mechanical" proof given in Archimedes' "Method", which is much more fun.

Comment: I understand, but regardless - in my opinion a mathematical work should be 100% rigorous. This means that, even if you don't show all your steps, you should indicate where they've been jumped and how you jumped them. That's what I've learnt from Walter Rudin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\angle LKM>\angle HOC$ it follows we can construct point $M'$ on side $LM$ such that $\angle LKM'=\angle HOC$. Then triangles $LKM'$, $COH$ are similar.

In triangle $KMM'$ we have $\angle M'> 90° > \angle M$, hence $KM>KM'$ (Euclid I-19) and:
$$
{KM\over KL}>{KM'\over KL}={OC\over OH}.
$$

Comment: Would you agree that the following, proposition 4, is redundant? Since the circle sector is also present in proposition 3 which was proved to be correct.

Comment: @AlabinescuRadu There is a small change in the proof, because the angle to be bisected is now the one subtending the sector. That's why it's treated separately.

Comment: Ok, but the angle bisected at prop. 3 can also be considered a circle sector.

Comment: @AlabinescuRadu But prop. 3 only deals with sectors whose angle is $360°/2^n$, while prop. 4 deals with any sector.

Answer (score 2):

Let me address the issue of why the following implication is true:
$$\angle HOC < \angle LKM \implies MK : LK > OC : OH
$$
Although it is of course impossible to know what Archimedes was thinking, it is my impression that an understanding of trigonometry was well established in the ancient Mediterranean. I suspect that Archimedes knew his trigonometry very, very well; this snippet of his works that you have provided in your post is evidence for that suspicion.

The inequality in question can be translated, in modern terms, into a fact about trigonometry: When the secant function is restricted to the interval $[0,\pi/2)$ the resulting function
$$\sec : [0,\pi/2) \to [1,\infty)
$$
is strictly increasing:
$$\theta < \phi \implies \sec\theta < \sec\phi
$$
One can observe this fact by inspecting a [graph of the secant function](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cosec-and-sec-graphs/). This can also be proved rigorously using calculus (and Archimedes knew his calculus pretty well too).

We can apply this implication to derive the inequality in question, as follows:

- letting $\theta = \angle HOC$ it follows that $\sec \theta = OC / OH$.
- letting $\phi = \angle LKM$ it follows that $\sec \phi = MK / LK$.

In a bit more detail, in any right triangle the secant of one of the acute angles is equal to the length of the hypotenuse divided by the length of the leg of the triangle that is adjacent to the given angle. So for example in the right triangle $OHC$, the secant of the angle $\theta = \angle HOC$ is equal to the length of the hypotenuse $OC$ divided by the length of the adjacent leg $OH$.

So Archimedes was right all along.

Comment: Thank you! I choose the latter proof because it is more simple than yours, although I also like this a lot. However, the graph of the secant function is quite difficult to grasp, and for sure, if Archimedes used this, he "knew his trigonometry very very well". I preferred the latter demonstration because, in my opinion, it is more plausible for Archimedes to use such a straightforward mode of demonstration, since he seems quite evasive in some of his proofs (like this one). In other words, he clearly doesn't illustrate all the steps (so he's not 100% rigorous).